# Extracting Lat/lng data for a list of places in an automated way

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, scripting

I have a list of 1663 place/address and i need for each of it the Lat/Lng using the address as an input or search criteria. is there a way to automate the task of finding lat/lng by place address using google map api?

Thanks,

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "ur adress"     
$string = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$data&sensor=true_or_false"));
$lat = $string->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $string->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

as inspiration in php

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i can javascript it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding btw u should take a break between the query, google like to answer sometimes with zero results

Comment: Thank you @StefanBD